# How to add item from quick edit mode to form library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

How to add items from quick edit mode to form library?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to enable the quick edit mode from Library Settings : Advanced Settings.
   [image]
2. Then click on library tab and choose 'Quick edit'.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

**List:** One is using the Quick Edit command on the ribbon, and the other is using the shortcut edit at the top of the list.

**Library:** using the Quick Edit command on the ribbon

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not do quick edit for new form in form library.

Possibility is that `drag file` or add `InfoPath form as webpart` in SitePage and link up it into quick launch.